# Create dynamic calculated member based on dimensions selected ON ROWS

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

Is there a way to create a dynamic calculated member based on the dimension selected ON ROWS?
I have the following example with 2 dimensions [Dim1].[Dim1] and [Dim2].[Dim2], with a measure [Measures].[Measure] and a calculated member [Measures].[CalculatedMeasure]:

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[CalculatedMeasure] AS 
 IIF([Dim1].[Dim1]**.....IS SELECTED ON ROWS.........**,
 [Measures].[Measure]
 /
 ([Measures].[Measure], [Dim1].[Dim1].CurrentMember.Parent),

 [Measures].[Measure]
  /
  ([Measures].[Measure], [Dim2].[Dim2].CurrentMember.Parent))

  SELECT {[Measures].[Measure],[Measures].[CalculatedMeasure]} ON COLUMNS ,
  {[Dim2].[Dim2].Members)} ON ROWS
  FROM [DataBase]
```

What I want is that when I select [Dim2].[Dim2] ON ROWS, the calculated member should be the result of

```
 [Measures].[Measure]
  /
 ([Measures].[Measure], [Dim2].[Dim2].CurrentMember.Parent)
```

ELSE

```
 [Measures].[Measure]
  /
 ([Measures].[Measure], [Dim1].[Dim1].CurrentMember.Parent)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Analysis Services, your `[Dim1].[Dim1]**.....IS SELECTED ON ROWS.........**`  could be coded as

```
Axis(1).Item(0).Item(0).Hierarchy IS [Dim1].[Dim1]
```

if you can assume there is only one hierarchy on the rows.

Here, `Axis(1)` returns the rows axis as set. I am not sure if this function is supported by Pentaho/Mondrian. Then, the first `Item(0)` selects the first tuple of this set, and the second one returns the first member of that tuple. Finally, the `Hierarchy` function returns the hierarchy of a member.

To extend this to queries containing up to three hierarchies in the rows, you would write

```
Axis(1).Item(0).Item(0).Hierarchy IS [Dim1].[Dim1] OR
Axis(1).Item(0).Item(1).Hierarchy IS [Dim1].[Dim1] OR
Axis(1).Item(0).Item(2).Hierarchy IS [Dim1].[Dim1]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it seems that Mondrian hasn't
implemented the Axis(n) function. I get the error: MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Syntax error at line , column , token 'Axis'. Is there a workaround?